# Having issues sorting with links in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, pdo

So, I am trying to sort a database by clickable links.  I have a function that is supposed to order them, but for some reason it isn't working.  Also, once I add something to the database and submit, if I click on the links to order, it sends me to my actual function holding file in the url, which is weird.

Forgive table formatting issues.  I'm still debugging that.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Project 1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 style='text-align:center;'>Movie Collection Database</h1>
    <form method='post' action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <table align='center' border='1' cellpadding='5'>
        <tr>
            <td>

                    <input type="text" size='40' name="movieTitle"  value="Movie Title">

            </td>
            <td>

                     <input type="text" name="studioName" value="Studio Name">

            </td>

            <td>
                <select name="movieRating">
                    <option value="G">G</option>
                    <option value="PG">PG</option>
                    <option value="PG-13">PG-13</option>
                    <option value="R">R</option>
                    <option value="NC-17">NC-17</option>
                    <option value="Not Rated">Not Rated</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>

                     <input type="text" name="publicationYear" value="2015">

            </td>

            <td>

                     <input type="number" name="imdbRating" value="10.0">

            </td>
            <td>

                     <input type="number" name="runTime" value="0">

            </td>
            <td>

                     <input type="checkbox" name="add">Add

            </td>
        </tr>   
        </table>

    <?php
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=berkleyr", "berkleyr", "12345");
    ?>
<?php include_once("Project1DB.php"); ?>

 <?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST"):



 delete($db);

 if(isset($_POST['add']))
 {
 try
 {
     Insert($db, $_POST['movieTitle'], $_POST['studioName'],   $_POST['movieRating'], $_POST['publicationYear'], $_POST['imdbRating'], $_POST['runTime']);
 }
 catch (PDOException $error)
 {
     $db->rollback();
     echo "Bad things Happened";
     $db = null;

     die("Connection failed: " . $error->getMessage());
 }
}


 ?>

 <table align='center' border='1'>




  <tr>
      <th><a href="Project1DB.php?orderBy=title">Title</a></th>
      <th><a href="Project1DB.php?orderBy=studio">Studio Name</a></th>
      <th><a href="Project1DB.php?orderBy=rating">Rating</a></th>
      <th><a href="Project1DB.php?orderBy=pub_year">Pub Year</a></th>
      <th><a href="Project1DB.php?orderBy=imdb_rating">IMDB Rating</a></th>
      <th><a href="Project1DB.php?orderBy=run_time">Run Time</a></th>
      <th>Delete</th>
  </tr>
 <?php foreach (Select($db) as $row): ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['title']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['studio']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['rating']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['pub_year']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['imdb_rating']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['run_time']; ?></td>
<?php echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='". $row['id'] . "' value='" . $row['id'] . "'></td>";?>
</tr> 
<?php endforeach ?>



<?php

if (isset($db))
{
$db = null; // make sure an exception didn't already close the connection. If not, close it now.
}

?>

<?php else: ?>

    <table align='center' border="1">
        <tr>
            <th><a href="?orderBy=title">Title</a></th>
            <th><a href="?orderBy=studio">Studio Name</a></th>
            <th><a href="?orderBy=rating">Rating</a></th>
            <th><a href="?orderBy=pub_year">Pub Year</a></th>
            <th><a href="?orderBy=imdb_rating">IMDB Rating</a></th>
            <th><a href="?orderBy=run_time">Run Time</a></th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach (Select($db) as $row): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['title']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['studio']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['rating']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['pub_year']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['imdb_rating']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['run_time']; ?></td>
                <?php echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='". $row['id'] ."' value='" . $row['id'] . "'></td>";?>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach ?>

<?php endif ?>
        <td colspan="7" align="center">
            <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Update Database' />
        </td>
    </table>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my function for sorting:

```
function orderBy($order)
    {

        switch($order)
            {
            case "title":
            $sorted = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM movie ORDER BY movie.title ASC");
            break;

        case "studio":
            $sorted = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM movie ORDER BY movie.studio ASC");
            break;

        case "rating":
            $sorted = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM movie ORDER BY movie.rating ASC");
            break;

        case "pub_year":
            $sorted = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM movie ORDER BY movie.pub_year ASC");
            break;

        case "imdb_rating":
            $sorted = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM movie ORDER BY movie.imdb_rating ASC");
            break;

        case "run_time":
            $sorted = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM movie ORDER BY movie.run_time ASC");
            break;

        }
$sorted->execute();
}
```

Comment: Where is `orderby` called? Probably be easier to just append the `order by..` to the end of the query than writing full query each case. Also `orderby` isnt outputting or returning..

Comment: @chris85 I honestly have no idea what the best way to sort this.  I'm just trying to pull stuff out of my rump.  And orderby is called in the places like this: <th><a href="Project1DB.php?orderBy=title">Title</a></th>

Comment: Hard to say in that case. Are you using a framework, I haven't seen a `Select` function. Currently `orderBy` isn't being used since you aren't calling it.

Comment: @chris85 I am not.  I'm just starting to learn PHP so I'm learning it the hard way.  I have the select function just selecting the database things I need:

function Select($db)
    {
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM movie");
    $query->execute();
    return $query->fetchAll();
    }

Comment: Did you figure out your issue?

Comment: @Rasclatt I did, I just can't figure out how to flag this as solved.